# how to store the multiple values in a mysql user defined variable

Tags: mysql, variables

How can i store the multiple values in a mysql user defined variable

In general ,

```
select @a:=color from tabex;
```

where `tabex` is as follows

```
mysql> select * from tabex;

+----+----------+-------+-----------+
| id | personid | color | color_set |
+----+----------+-------+-----------+
|  1 |        1 | red   | red,white |
|  2 |        1 | white | red,white |
|  3 |        2 | blue  | NULL      |
|  4 |        2 | red   | NULL      |
+----+----------+-------+-----------+
```

then after if i perform the query

```
mysql> select @a;

+------+
| @a   |
+------+
| red  |
+------+
```

i am getting the above result ,  but actually i want the following result

```
+-------+
|  @a   |
+-------+
| red   |
| white |
| blue  |
| red   |
+-------+
```

can you please any body tell me , is this possible or not in mysql .

simply my question is how to store the multiple values in mysql user defined variables

Comment: this is possible.. user defined variables store one value.. so to store multiple you would have to make a concatenated string. `GROUP_CONCAT(color)` would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following sentence to get all results as a string

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(color) from tabex;
```

click [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) or more information

Comment: If you're looking at a large query result though, there's a very important limit here that deserves to be explicitly mentioned: "The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of max_allowed_packet."